# Best practices for reusing prepared statements while keeping the code clean?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

**TL;DR**: What's the recommended approach for reusing `PreparedStatement` objects in Java, without making a mess out of the code?

- If I want to reuse them I have to define them all early in the code, and it becomes a mess.
- If I don't create them until I need to, I can keep the code tidy and clean, but then I can't reuse the objects.

---

I have a method like this:

```java
PreparedStatement psQuery = conn.prepareStatement("select ...");
PreparedStatement psChild = conn.prepareStatement("select ... where parent = ? and ...");
ResultSet rsQuery = psQuery.executeQuery();
while (rsQuery.next()) {
    psChild.setInt(1, rsQuery.getInt("id"));
    psChild.executeQuery();
    ...
}
```

I create two `preparedStatement` first, and then reuse them every time I need to execute those specific SQL queries. I don't define `psChild` inside my loop because then I'd be *creating* a new prepared statement in each iteration, instead of just reusing it.

Now, my code is much more complex. I'm actually using 13 different `preparedStatement` instances, and the code spreads through a few hundred lines. I'd *very much* like to split it into different methods, but I'm not sure how to properly do it. I can think of two options. The first one is like I'm doing it right now, only splitting into methods:

```java
PreparedStatement psQuery = conn.prepareStatement("select ...");
PreparedStatement psChild = conn.prepareStatement("select ... where parent = ? and ...");
ResultSet rsQuery = psQuery.executeQuery();
while (rsQuery.next()) {
    processChildren(rsQuery.getInt("id"), psChild);
}
```

The problem is, I end up with a `processChildren` with this signature:

```java
private static void processChild(
    ...,
    final PreparedStatement psFoo,
    final PreparedStatement psBar,
    final PreparedStatement psDoc,
    final PreparedStatement psGrumpy,
    final PreparedStatement psHappy,
    final PreparedStatement psSleepy,
    final PreparedStatement psDopey,
    final PreparedStatement psBashful,
    final PreparedStatement psSneezy,
    final PreparedStatement psYetAnotherOne,
    final PreparedStatement psAndAnotherOne,
    final PreparedStatement psLastOne,
    ...) {
```

Not exactly great.

The other option would be to create each prepared statement in the method where I'll need it. That would be much cleaner, but it's the same as creating them inside the loop: I wouldn't be reusing them.

There is yet another option, to declare the variables as class attributes, this way I could create them first, and then reuse without the need to clutter the "children method" signatures. But this feels even more wrong, in the same way that using a global variable would. Worse, 13 "global" variables all of them with the same class and very similar names. No way I'm doing that!

How could I proceed?

<sub>Note: I'm aware of much better persistence solutions, such as JPA. I'm not looking for an alternative to prepared statements, I only want to know what's the usual approach in cases like mine.</sub>

---

**Edit**: It seems like I oversimplified my example. This is closer to what I need to do:

1. Retrieve all the records from database 1.
2. For each one of them (first loop):
3. Check if it exists in another database 2.
4. If it doesn't, create it in database 2, and:
5. Retrieve all children from database 1.
6. For each of the children (second loop):
7. Check if child exists in database 2.
8. If it doesn't, then insert it.

So I have two levels of nested loops which I can't get rid of. And creating the prepared statements over and over inside of the loops seems like a poor idea.

Comment: Hard to comment about the 13 statements. But for the code that is shown you could write a join and use only one prepared statement. And yes making them class variables would be horrible, it would not be threadsafe. the prepared statement isn’t something you can reuse across different connections.

Comment: why you are create them in a loop? can't you create 1 SQL which include the secondary SQL?

Comment: As others said, in that given example case you could probably merge those two statements into one. If we ignore that, what about splitting it into multiple methods, each with its own statement? `findParents` for the first statement returning a collection of some objects, and `findChildren` which would take that collection and return some other collection.

Comment: It seems like I oversimplified my example :) I'll edit the question

Comment: PreparedStatements can still not be used concurrently, so I tend to try-wtih-resources locally. There are also JDBC template libraries, like in XML format. 20 PreparedStatement variables is too ugly.

Comment: @NathanHughes I'm not using any connection pool. It's not a webapp, it's a very simple command line app, intended to be used just once, to migrate some data from a system to another. Which is why we didn't bother with Hibernate or JPA, just plain JDBC. But I still would like the code to be well organized and readable :)

Comment: you might consider DBAs have tools for one-time data moves. jdbc may be the wrong tool for the job.